# how to push gradle plugin(not android library) to jcenter(or maven mavenCentral)?

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-plugin, jcenter

I wrote a plugin，want publish to jcenter(or other repo).
then can import by rootProject#build.gradle#classpath.
No longer use File.

How can I do it?(I can publish android library，but can't do this )

Answer (score 0):

You can easily publish your plugin using the `java-gradle-plugin`, see official documentation there : https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html#sec:using_the_java_gradle_plugin_development_plugin ( and [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html#sec:publishing_your_plugin))

Example of use, which is publishing to a local maven repository (but you can adapt it to publish to any remote repository)

```
plugins {
    id 'java-gradle-plugin'
    id 'groovy'
    id 'maven-publish'
}
group 'org.gradle.sample.plugin'
version '0.1'

//  pugin metadata configuration
gradlePlugin {
    plugins {
        myplugin {
            id = "org.gradle.sample.plugin.myplugin"
            implementationClass = "org.gradle.sample.plugin.MyPlugin"
        }
    }
}
// publish to local maven repo for testing
publishing {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "../repos/maven-repo"
        }
    }
}
```

then execute:

```
./gradlew publish
```

Comment: No problem uploading to local warehouse
However, uploading to mavenCenter does not work. More complicated Settings are required, such as the account number and the location of the file after I successfully upload it